# What is the purpose/effect of |\s? in ([\s\S]+|\s?)

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the purpose or the effect of `|\s?` in `([\s\S]+|\s?)`?  Wouldn't the expression be the same without it as `([\s\S]+)`?

Comment: The first regex matches an empty string, while the second does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't *exactly* the same. `([\s\S]+|\s?)` would match an empty string, while `([\s\S]+)` would not.

However, `([\s\S]*)` would be equivalent.

Comment: Or the same as `/.*/`.

Comment: @RobG Not quite, `'\nfoo'.match(/.*/)` → `['']`, `'\nfoo'.match(/[\s\S]*/)` → `['\nfoo']`

Answer (score 0):

that means either `one or more of all characters` or only `one or zero space`

`[\s\S]+` is equivalent to `.+`

and `\s?` means an optional `space`

Comment: Only with DOTALL. Since this is tagged Javascript, your second statement is incorrect since `.` does *not* match `\n`.